# Ancher font-size in dropdown menu changes in mobile browsers

Tags: android, html, css, iphone

I have created a CSS/HTML-only dropdown menu. When a mouse hovers over the parent link, the hidden dropdown menu appears. On mobile devices it seems that the anchors containing a hidden menu suddenly have a smaller font-size compared to the other anchors. On desktop, the font-size stays the same like any other link.

- Why are mobile devices making the font-size smaller/bigger for these anchors?
- How can I avoid this behavior?

Full code & working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xj3jc/

```
<ul class="topmenu_parent">
  <li class="topmenu_link"><a href="home/index">Home</a></li>
  <li class="topmenu_link dropdown_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown_parent">Account</a>
    <div class="dropdown_links">
      <a href="users/profile/1">Mijn profiel</a>
      <a href="users/edit/email">Bewerk e-mail</a>
      <a href="users/edit/password">Bewerk wachtwoord</a>
      <a href="users/search">Zoek gebruiker</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="topmenu_link dropdown_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown_parent">Berichten</a>
    <div class="dropdown_links">
      <a href="messages/inbox">Inkomend</a>
      <a href="messages/outbox">Uitgaand</a>
      <a href="messages_create/form">Nieuw bericht</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="topmenu_link dropdown_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown_parent">Pronostiek</a>
    <div class="dropdown_links">
      <a href="predictions/index/1">Jupiler Pro League</a>
      <a href="predictions/index/2">Champions League (voorronde)</a>    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="topmenu_link dropdown_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown_parent">Scorebord</a>
    <div class="dropdown_links">
      <a href="predictions/score/1">Jupiler Pro League</a>
      <a href="predictions/score/2">Champions League (voorronde)</a>    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="topmenu_link"><a href="home/faq">FAQ</a></li>
  <li class="topmenu_link"><a href="home/logout">Log uit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile:
[image]

Comment: Have you explicit set the anchor's font size in your CSS?

Comment: No I didn't (full HTML/CSS is included in the JSFiddle example). Is this because mobile browsers make links bigger to be easier to click on - and the mobile browser recognizes the JS and doesn't resize those anchors?

Comment: As I don't have an iPhone to test and compare I can't say, though when it comes to font size's one should always set them as the browsers predefined style sheets differs.

Comment: Tested on my Windows 10 Mobile, same issue, bigger fonts on those links

Comment: Found it ... posted an answer for you

Comment: Thanks! I was trying out all your suggestions but didn't find anything that worked, I'm very happy that you went through with it and found the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is link with drop down menus is displayed `inline-block`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/fL4xj3jc/8/)

So do this change

```
.topmenu_link
{
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* you can delete this rule */
/* li.dropdown_button
{
    display: inline-block;
} */
```

Comment: Thanks, this works wonderful and I end up with less code. Were you able to use the dropdown menu itself on an Android phone? I haven't been able to test the JS addition on anything other than an iPhone. Before the JS addition, it just zoomed in a second before going to the parent link, making the menu useless.

Comment: @Max Tested on Windows 10 Mobile, had same issue, work after update ... and I'm sure it works on Android now

Answer (score 0):

just remove the click behaviour of your link :

```
var dropParents = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown_parent');

for (var i = 0; i < dropParents.length; i++) {
  dropParents[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Or in css but not supported by IE < 11:

```
.dropdown_parent {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: The click behavior is already removed, I was wondering why the size changed for certain anchors.